# Calling thread.notify() on a callers thread that is no longer available

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

On this page [link](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) on the first example, b.wait() is called. What would happend if b.wait() was never called, and the main thread was allowed to finish before the b thread was able to call notify()? Would an exception happen or would it do something funky? I could not find anything on the internet specific to this because I don't really know how to search for that situation. Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What do you expect would happen?

Comment: A `notify()` does absolutely nothing at all if no other thread is waiting for it.  In fact, that's the source of a common newbie mistake:  Noobs are often surprised when thread A calls `o.notify()` before thread B calls `o.wait()`, and then thread B ends up waiting forever.

Answer (score 0):

`notify()` doesn't have anything to do with whether the target thread is still running, or indeed whether the target is a thread at all. All that will happen is ... nothing.